# how can change asp.net web config appsettion key value and resolve the issue of login session end

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-config

I have code in my project which is changing a value of an appsetting key value

```
string session = Session["emailid"].ToString();
string Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserNameId"].ToString();
string intValue = Value;
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("UserNameId");
int Chagege = Convert.ToInt32(intValue);
Chagege++;
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("UserNameId", Chagege.ToString());
config.Save();
Session["emailid"] = session.ToString();
```

The code is working well there is an a issue on session end where we are rewriting the web.config file and change the key value. How can i can keep the session during with the changed value in the web.config? Any one have a any Idea how can i fix this issue?

Comment: **PLEASE**: don't write in ALL CAPS - first of all it's really hard to read, and secondly it's considered **shouting** at people - it's rude and not popular, so please stop doing that - thanks

Comment: sure i did that now i was not know about this CAPS case issue here thanks you for know me about this marc_s

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify your config file. That will *always* cause a loss of session.

Comment: so you mean i have to use different xml file for that do that task?

Comment: Yes. Your config file is not meant to be modified, except to, rarely, _change the configuration_.

Comment: hmmm can you please give me some example links so i can see

Comment: Examples of not changing your config file?